# Laravel: How to show all posts which category is not blocked?

Tags: laravel, relationships

I have models User, Category and Post. Post belongs to many users and many categories. User and Category are not related. I created a custom pivot table in which i store user_id and category_id, and a model CategoryBlock for that table. How can I get all posts which category the user didn't block?

Comment: May be it will be post belong to user and user has many post. On the other hand post belongs to category and category has many post.

Comment: your relations are wrong at first place, post belongs to many users is only when users belons to many post this is many to many relation should have post_user pivot

Comment: @DorienCragen One user has many posts. If it was a many to many relationship, there would be many authors on one post which I don't want.

Comment: @MahfuzShishir Yes, that is how I set it up

Comment: so should me user has many post and post bengs to user

Comment: @DorienCragen User can have many posts, that is not the problem. The problem is how to show all posts on homepage except the blocked ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

easiest way is to get all block categories and then get post where not in this collection

**EDIT**

```
$block = DB::table('category_block')->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get()->pluck(['category_id'])->toArray();

$posts = Post::whereNotIn('category_id', $block)->get();
```

Comment: That's the thing I needed. Thanks. But only now it shows error "Trying to get property of non-object" when trying to get all the user id's

Comment: ok this is because i assume you have logged user here and session, you have to change `Auth::user()->id` actual valid user_id